# How to make calendar modal using sublime text 3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

how can I make it in modal? I try other codes, and the same output is always the feature appear in the footer instead in a modal. Thanks for the help

```
 <div id="calendar"></div>

<div id="createEventModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Create Event</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="createAppointmentForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputCow">Cow ID:</label>
            <div class="controls">
               <input type="text" name="cowName" id="cowName" style="margin: 0;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEvent">Event:</label>
            <div class="controls">
               <input type="text" name="eventName" id="eventName" tyle="margin: 0;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="5" data-source="[&quot; Last Estrus&quot;,&quot; Next Estrus&quot;]">
                  <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTime"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="when">When:</label>
            <div class="controls controls-row" id="when" style="margin-top:5px;">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKIIN.png)

Comment: I guess you miss the js initialization of the modal.

Comment: how do you want to open a model?by click  or any other event  of any element and which calendar plugin you are using? display in output image

Comment: by clicking the date, iwant to pop out the modal https://jsfiddle.net/milz/fotLoLy9/ here's the based of the plug in I used

Comment: whenever I try it to jsfiddle, it works fine, but when I put it in sublime. The modal part was gone